# Link to download Office SharePoint Server 2007 October 2010 Cumulative Update

Tags: 2007, cumulative-update

I am trying to locate the link to download Office SharePoint Server 2007 Cumulative Update - October 2010,  however I am alwasy being landed in [KB2412267](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2412267/)

Above KB article contains every details apart from link to download the installables.

I am able to get a link for WSS 3.0 - Oct 2010 [2412268](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2412268/) and it also contains link to download/request the hotfix.

Can someone help me with the link to download MOSS 2007 - October 2010 CU.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Down in the Resolutions section of the article you linked to is a reference to the packages for SharePoint and Project Server.

The SharePoint entry links to [KB2412259](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2412259) which has a link to the [request page](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2412259&kbln=en-us)